# Selenium can't find ninth element - python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with Selenium webdriver.

I want to log in a website and collect some articles from there. I could log in the website with my code, but couldn't find all elements.

This code can find all elements except ninth element of 'major' and 'notice'. (I don't know why but it could find ninth element of 'upload')

```
from selenium import webdriver
import MyCode

Data = []

....

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(MyCode.url[0])
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

major = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('board-lecture-title')
notice = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class=\'post-title\']/*')
upload = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('post-date')

....

driver.close()
```

This is a part of HTML code of the website

```
<li class="isnotice" style="width:calc(100% - 20px) !important;">
    <span class="post-title">
        <a href="https://url">
            <span class="board-lecture-title">[Course]</span>Title&nbsp;
        </a>
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="post-date">2020년 7월 30일, 목요일, 오전 10:58</span>
    <span class="post-viewinfo area-right">
        0
        <br>
        <span>View</span>
    </span>
</li>
<li class="isnotice" style="width:calc(100% - 20px) !important;">
    <span class="post-title">
        <a href="https://url">
            <span class="board-lecture-title">[Course]</span>Title&nbsp;
        </a>
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="post-date">2020년 7월 15일, 수요일, 오후 12:20</span>
    <span class="post-viewinfo area-right">
        0
        <br>
        <span>View</span>
    </span>
</li>
<li class="isnotice" style="width:calc(100% - 20px) !important;">
    <span class="post-title">
        <a href="https://url">
            <span class="board-lecture-title">[Course]</span>Title&nbsp;
        </a>
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="post-date">2020년 6월 29일, 월요일, 오전 11:18</span>
    <span class="post-viewinfo area-right">
        47
        <br>
        <span>View</span>
    </span>

....

</ul>
```

I'm sorry for my poor english give you confusion.

Comment: Could you please add your code where you are trying to access the ninth element. Also it is better to add the error message and logs.

Comment: Okay, I will add more information next time. Actually, I don't have any to access element so I have to make somewhere.